# GCP cost type through billing data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, flat, ondemand

I have GCP billing data, where I have all the columns such as : 'sku_id',  'service_id', 'service_description', 'sku_description'. How to get cost type for a given a row such as on-demand v/s flat-rate ? I dont have pricing_model column.

I have columns list as given below : [ 'billing_account_id', 'service', 'sku',
'usage_start_time', 'usage_end_time', 'project', 'labels',
'system_labels', 'location', 'resource', 'tags', 'price', 'export_time',
'cost', 'currency', 'currency_conversion_rate', 'usage', 'credits',
'invoice', 'cost_type', 'adjustment_info', 'cost_at_list', 'sku_id',
'service_id', 'service_description', 'sku_description']

How to get cost type for a given a row ?